# How can I get result by using “execute ‘delete from table1'"

Tags: postgresql

when I use execute command to run a sql cmd, I want to get the result of it.
As we know, I can get total counts by variable `sc` when I use :

```
execute 'select * from table" into sc;
```

But How can I get result by using:

```
execute 'delete from table1'"?
```

when I use INTO, it turns out

```
ERROR: "INTO used with a command that cannot return data"
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want a result why are you deleting from the table rather than selecting from it?

Comment: I just want to return how many rows I have delete by using "delete from"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear to me what you are trying to do, but you should be able use "RETURNING".  Here I am just returning the rows that were deleted:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo(id int, description text);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES
(1, 'HELLO'),
(2, 'WORLD');

DELETE FROM foo returning *;
+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | HELLO       |
|  2 | WORLD       |
+----+-------------+
(2 rows)
```

Also, if you need them moved "into" a table (for example), you could do something like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deleted_foo;

CREATE TEMP TABLE foo(id int, description text);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES
(1, 'HELLO'),
(2, 'WORLD');

CREATE TEMP TABLE deleted_foo(id int, description text);

WITH x AS (DELETE FROM foo RETURNING *)
INSERT INTO deleted_foo
SELECT * FROM x;

SELECT * FROM deleted_foo;

+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | HELLO       |
|  2 | WORLD       |
+----+-------------+
(2 rows)
```

Assuming that you are doing this from inside a plpgsql function, you could also use the `ROW_COUNT` variable.  For example:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
```

This would give you the number of rows that were deleted.

Answer (score 2):

```
execute 'WITH row_deleted AS (DELETE FROM table1 RETURNING *) SELECT count(*) FROM row_deleted' into c;
```

You can use it inside a plsql funtion as following:

```
--Drop the table and the functin if it exist:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

DROP FUNCTION if exists _deleted_rows();
--Create the table for the example:
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  row_id serial NOT NULL,
  col1 character varying,
  CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (row_id)
);

--Insert some rows:
insert into table1 (col1) values ('test1');
insert into table1 (col1) values ('test2');
insert into table1 (col1) values ('test3');

--Ctreate the function that count the number of deleted rows of the table: table1
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _deleted_rows()
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$declare 
nbr_deleted  integer;
begin
    execute 'WITH row_deleted AS (DELETE FROM table1 RETURNING *) SELECT count(*) FROM row_deleted' into nbr_deleted;
    return (nbr_deleted);
end;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Test that function (got problem building shema on sqlfidlle):

```
select * from _deleted_rows();

 _deleted_rows
---------------
 3
(1 ligne)
```

[Execute](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/plpgsql-statements.html) command

[DELETE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) command

Comment: Can WITH query support "DELETE FROM"? it doesn't work.

Comment: @SimonSu Yes it does, i just updated my answer with an complete example!

Comment: Thanks for your help, It helps me a lot, I use GET DIAGNOSTICS instead for I just want to debug my sql query.